# (discord.py) Get user's, last message from a JSON file without specifying the name/id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have an *users.json* file which store the user's id and `lmessage` (current date,time) if he is write in a room.

```
{"5314934047066510132": {"lmessage": "2021-04-21 10:21:01"}}
```

How can I get all of these IDs and the `lmessage`s which belongs to that ID without specify username or anything?

Currently I can get the user's `lmessage` with a command if I specify the username:

```py
@client.command()
async def lastmess(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    id = member.id
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    lastmessage = users[str(id)]['lmessage']
    await ctx.send(f'{member} Last message: {lastmessage}!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to iterate through all of the key-value pairs in the JSON data. If so, you can use the various dictionary methods available:

```py
with open("users.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Get all keys (user IDs)
user_ids = list(data.keys())   # OR list(data)

# Get all values (last message dictionary)
last_messages = list(data.values())

# Get all keys and values tuples
ids_and_last_messages = list(data.items())

# Get all last message dates
last_message_dates = [uid["lmessage"] for uid in data.values()]
```

Comment: Thank you... ~15 chars

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how you would like to output the result,
but this is how to can get all the IDs without specify the user
and you can edit that to output or display the result as you want

```
@client.command()
async def lastmess(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
  id = member.id
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
  for user in users:
    print(user, user['lmessage'])  # here you can print all the IDS/lmessage
  lastmessage = users[str(id)]['lmessage']
  await ctx.send(f'{member} Last message: {lastmessage}!')
```

Comment: I tried your answer too, but `discord.member = None` doesn't works, getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`error